# chromedriver does not have .exe after extracting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have downloaded te latest chromedriver 2.46 and extracted the chrome driver but it has no .exe extension and when i run the code the error appears, i also tried using 7zip when extracting.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf4hb.png)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class SelTest {
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://google.com");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are fetching the chromedriver, your "the code" link is giving 404.

Comment: i have add the code thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add .exe in the chromedriver path and then it would work.
Like:
    `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Explorer is configured not to show known file extension - this includes ".exe". See also the archives in your screenshot - they also don't have their ".zip" :)

Just set as environment variable the chromedriver with the .exe appended at the end, and you'll be fine:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

And here's a (random from the net) pic how to make Explorer show the extensions:

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-ssl.com](https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/show-file-extensions.jpg))</sub>